# MS ACCESS - One Data form to fill multiple lines of data in a master data table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Is it possible to fill up one form and have multiple data lines filled in my data table?
As there is information such as department and time in, time out which will be the same, and only the employee names differ. I do not want to enter the data line by line as its time consuming.

If its possible, can i have the list of employee where i can pick from, filtered tot he department which I have selected at the top? (refer to picture)

Comment: There is no picture in question. Yes, 'batch' creating records is possible. Does this answer your question? [Create Multiple Records in One Form. Only One Field Changes per Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245849/create-multiple-records-in-one-form-only-one-field-changes-per-record)

Comment: Would a way to make your data entry heaps faster be a valid solution?   
(try using CTRL + '  and then tab to the next field) to copy the entry from the field in the row above - for all the cells that are the same...)