# Generate Records to Add to Table - Loop or Recordset?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I wrote a database for a soil drilling department, and I have a form where a user sets up a new project and it asks how many borings will be drilled for that project.  The user enters a number, and that's the number of borings that should get added to the Borings table when they click on Add Project button.  The Boring Numbers should be sequentially numbered as B-1, B-2, B-3 etc. and tmpProjectID should be inserted as the ProjectID for these borings.

I know it should be a fairly simple loop, but I've never written a loop before, and I could really use help writing a loop that can do this.  I've already searched this site and online, but I don't know what some parts of the code mean so I can't figure out how to modify/apply it to my database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Multiple Records in One Form. Only One Field Changes per Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245849/create-multiple-records-in-one-form-only-one-field-changes-per-record). Your question title is not a good one. What you need is not really a decision between loop or recordset, quite likely relevant code will use both. You apparently deleted prior question on this topic. This question is not an improvement.

Comment: The referred link helps, but since I'm not that familiar with writing loops or running code for recordsets, I'm struggling with modifying the code and applying it to my database. I'm a beginner at VBA, so I'm not sure what I need or how to phrase my question. In my previous post, I was asking for help on 2 connected problems, but you asked me to separate them, so I did. I wanted to start over, so deleted the first post and started with the first question (this post). I'm just trying to ask for help, but since I don't know how to phrase things, my questions keep getting closed.

Comment: However, after watching some YouTube videos, I've finally managed to modify and apply the code for my database, but I'm getting errors.  I will ask for help in a new post.