# Multiple record with one button in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I want to add records on continuous form with one click.see below detail in pic.
If possible explain please.
[multiple record in ms access with one button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1qhr.png)

Comment: Batch creating records is a common topic. More than one way to approach. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Multiple Records in One Form. Only One Field Changes per Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245849/create-multiple-records-in-one-form-only-one-field-changes-per-record)

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: I spent more time than usual on this particular question about inserting multiple records: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175837/populating-multiple-fields-in-subform-using-combobox-and-afterupdate-event-prodc/70184495#70184495

Answer (score 0):

Collect your variables in collections or arrays and loop these while adding records:

```
Public Function BuildProducts() As Long

    Dim Records         As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Sizes           As New Collection
    Dim Item            As Variant
    
    Dim Colors(0 To 1)  As String
    
    Dim ProductCode As Long
    Dim ProductName As String
    Dim Rate        As Currency
    Dim Quantity    As Long
    Dim Index       As Long
    Dim Counter     As Long
    
    ' Retrieve common values.
    ProductCode = Nz(DMax("productcode", "product"))
    ProductName = Me![Product Name].Value
    Rate = Me!Rate.Value
    Quantity = Me!Qty.Value   
    
    ' Create collection and array.
    If Me!CheckboxSmall.Value = True Then
        Sizes.Add "Small"
    End If
    If Me!CheckboxMedium.Value = True Then
        Sizes.Add "Medium"
    End If
    If Me!CheckboxLarge.Value = True Then
        Sizes.Add "Large"
    End If
    
    Colors(0) = Me!Color1.Value
    Colors(1) = Me!Color2.Value
    
    ' Create records.
    ' Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From product", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
    ' However, the from is bound to the table, so use the RecordsetClone:
    Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone
    
    For Index = LBound(Colors) To UBound(Colors)
        Debug.Print Colors(Index)
        For Each Item In Sizes
            Debug.Print , Item
            ProductCode = ProductCode + 1
            Records.AddNew
                Records!ProductCode.Value = ProductCode
                Records!ProductName.Value = ProductName
                Records!Rate.Value = Rate
                Records!qty.Value = Quantity
                Records!Size.Value = Item
                Records!Color.Value = Colors(Index)
            Records.Update
            Counter = Counter + 1
        Next
    Next
    Records.Close
    
    BuildProducts = Counter

End Function
```

[image]

Call it like this from your button:

```vb
Private Sub CreateProductsButton_Click()

    Dim Counter As Long
    
    Counter = BuildProducts
    MsgBox CStr(Counter) & " records created"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What would be command button vba?

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: Some error shows after button click.   " Compile error invalid use of me keyword"

Comment: Then correct for that error. Code is tested and - as you can see - works perfectly well.

Comment: something like:    Rate will be according to size.

Comment: The code is made as an example to match the extremely little information you provided. If you have extended business rules, you must modify the code to adopt.

Comment: Table detail.  
Product id.  
Product name.  
Sku ( sku-size-color). 
Rate.  
Quantity.  
Size.  (Checkbox). 
Color. ( select from combobox or listbox).  

Rate also according to size e.g.

Comment: OK, but please understand, SO is not a code writing service, but a code _helping_ service. You have been given a complete and verified code example working with your original question, demonstrating how to apply fixed values, as well as two ways to collect and apply values with two or multiple options. That is a firm starting point from which you must proceed on your own. If you run into troubles, raise a new question about one issue only, and refer to this question if relevant.

Comment: Ok I understand your opinion. I have made multiple record form but there is only one problem is that when i press command button . It’s make record sometime but sometimes skip some record. I will share with you my vba code. Thanks

Comment: Hello!
it’s working fine but its not making record on new row. When i try to add on new record shows error

Comment: Yes, the record must be saved, and the (taken from your example) four _common values_ used in the code must be valid.

Comment: Ok but i want to add new record.

Comment: When i enter on already entered data its remove last record

Comment: For a new record (set of products), go to a new record, fill in the common values, make your selections for sizes and colours, save the record, run the code.

Comment: A record will only be removed if you _delete_ it. If you type in changed values on an existing record, it will be updated (if you don't cancel the update).

Comment: On new record it’s required to enter manually in row . When i enter in row manually then i select size and color. Otherwise error occurred “invalid null”

Comment: Yes. You can expand the code to check for _Null_ values or other invalid values and - if validation fails - exit the code without attempting to create records.

Comment: This problem is solved. 
I want to add different price according to checkbox. I try to assign textbox but only one textbox value shows in “rate”.