Creating Multiple New Records at Same Time in Existing Access/SQL Table
I have been asked by our company to begin work on a new Sample Register for test pieces we handle. I have found a way to append information to a list of samples once they have been allocated a number. I am currently trying to find a way for the user to input the samples initially, doing so by requsting potentially multiple samples at a time.
Samples can come in in varying quantities and so the ideal and what i am aiming to accomplish would be for them to request "n" number of samples against the specific Project Number with a date field for arrival date (that would be hand entered or auto to the current date), and for the existing table to then add the new records. The "n" would be determined from an unbound box on the input form in Access.
I have tried experimenting with Append Queries and temporary tables but couldnt get this to work consistently. I have explored some direct VBA coding options but have been unable to find advice that fits the requirements or doesnt end up with the suggestion of loading data in by other means which in this instance isnt an option. I did try to work out a way to get an Insert Into clause to repeat based on the "n" instances, but have not managed to make this work.
In additon to the Project No. and Date fields, the table has a PKey (AutoNumber), and 8 other fields, as well as a Calculated field (which is the Sample ID No.). For the Sample ID No. i am currently using a number of the other fields plus the PKey autonumber to create unique numbers as this seemed an elegant solution, but I can change that if that would prevent this working and use a different numbering system (i.e. starting with x no. and having each new one be the current Max of that column +1).
The Project No. field is selected from a drop down list created from the main list of projects and is either a 5 or 6 digit number. All dates are currently in short date format. The other fields are a mixture of Numbers or Long Text with a single Yes/No field.
Any guidance to source material or advice on a way to effect this would be appreciated.
Note: I have a moderate knowledge of Access but less so when it comes to VBA as i have tended to find simple ways to accomplish tasks without needing to code them previously.

Nice example from Gustav, however, in your case loop would iterate over sample sequence number, not a data range. This is really quite a common topic - here's another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245849/create-multiple-records-in-one-form-only-one-field-changes-per-record

Using the PK as part of SampleID is a complication. Saving this calculated value is probably not necessary. Build the composite ID when needed (in query or textbox on form/report). Is a sample record ever deleted? Do you need to account for gaps in sequence? Your loop would be like: For x = 1 To Me.tbxSmplQty. When you have actual code with issue, post a question.

@June7 - thanks for this. I was able to bastardize the code to accomplish what i needed. now i just have to work out how to append the code to then open the relevant form that i also want to open but shouldnt be too difficuly.

A comment on the coding used in the code on this page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245849/create-multiple-records-in-one-form-only-one-field-changes-per-record - how would i change the recordset to go to a SQL table, i.e., dbo.NAMEOFTABLE? Is there any special nomenclature thats required or can i just change the table reference as i have done in my testbed database?

Did you try it?
